# Как поменять цвет формы с ColorDialog?

Tags: c#

А почему не удалось поменять цвет формы

```
Form1.BackColor = colorDialog1.Color;
```

при помощи "ColorDialog"?

Comment: ForeColor это цвет шрифта. Вам нужен BackColor

Comment: извините опечатка

Answer (score 3):

Здравствуйте!

Первая ошибка, вы обращаетесь к классу Form1, в C# это грубая ошибка, в Visual Basic'e 6.0 такое можно было сделать, а вот в .NET уже нельзя... Надо написать так:

```
if (colorDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    this.ForeColor = colorDialog.Color;
}
```

Далее ещё одна ошибка, если вы хотите поменять цвет **формы**, а не цвет шрифта, то надо использовать не ForeColor, а BackColor.

Код для BackColor:

```
if (colorDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    this.BackColor = colorDialog.Color;
}
```